# How to Stop Screen Blinking Because of High Memory Usage?

Tags: graphics, xubuntu, intel, ram

I have a problem with **Xubuntu 18.04**.

The problem is, when I do something that uses a lot of memory (like watching YouTube videos, opening multiple tabs on Chromium, opening a tab on Chromium, or loading a heavy website), the screen doesn't update for 5-8 seconds, get filled with black for 1-2 seconds, then displays the GUI again (sometimes it doesn't update eventually, then I have to restart my PC).
On YouTube, when I open a video, it does the previous sequence 2-4 times continuously!

Besides Chromium and YouTube, that happens regularly (every 30 seconds to 3 minutes).

What do I do to prevent this problem? Tell me what information you need, and I'll give it to you.

Comment: 1.7 GB seems to be very short. You can check that with System Monitor - Resources.

Comment: @DominikCornice Where is that? I didn't find it in Xubuntu's settings manager. What's the command for it?

Comment: You can view the memory usage by using the htop application.

Answer (score 0):

Go in Chromium settings Disable hardware acceleration.
In the URL bar type `chrome://flags/` enable Override software rendering list.

Comment: I've tried that before, it doesn't work. The problem is not about Chromium, it's about RAM. @JerareYoshi